# scrollable activity in as3 is not working perfect for android air

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

i want to make a scrollable index of particular math book for android version where i will be able to scroll a movie clip consists of 56 child movieclips(there are chapter 1 to chapter 56 child clips has made "buttons_all" parentclip) and when i will choose a child movie clip it will go to selected label or chapter(suppose if i click chapter 1 movie clip it will gotoAndPlay("chapter 1")).i had made the parent movieclip scrollable and added eventlistener to each child movie clip..but when i want to scroll it is doing two things,first it scrolls then go to that "chapter" that i clicked to start scrolling whether i want to go this chapter or not.to solve that i added a timer event to create an interval to stop selecting chapter immediately before i want to select a specific chapter..but it is working partially.i want to add this interval to every button.because i dont have a scrollbar here for up and down..please help me to solve this..here is my part of code

```
 var pat1:MovieClip = scrolling_manu.buttons_all.part1;

    var listTimer:Timer; // timer for all events

     var tapDelayTime:Number = 0;
     var maxTapDelayTime:Number = 20; // change this to increase or descrease tap sensitivity

     var tapEnabled:Boolean = false;

 init();
 function init()
    {
        //removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        pat1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onmouseDown );
        //trace("hit");

         pat1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onmouseUp );
        listTimer = new Timer( 33 );
        listTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onListTimer);
        listTimer.start();

    }
    function onmouseDown( e:TouchEvent ):void 
    {

         handleItemPress()
    }
    function onmouseUp( e:TouchEvent ):void 
    {

        onTapDisabled();
        //listTimer.stop();
    }

 function onListTimer(e:Event):void
    {
        // test for touch or tap event
        if(tapEnabled)
            onTapDelay();


    }


    function onTapDisabled():void
    {

            tapEnabled = false;
            tapDelayTime = 0;

    }       
function onTapDelay():void

    {
        tapDelayTime++;

        if(tapDelayTime > maxTapDelayTime ) 
        {
            //tapItem.selectItem();
            tapDelayTime = 0;
            tapEnabled = false;
            trace("hit");
            pat1.gotoAndPlay("over1");
            pat1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onmouseUp );
        }

    }

    function handleItemPress()
    {
            tapDelayTime = 0;
            tapEnabled = true;
            trace("hit");

    }
```

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/c1bintro   here is the fla file

Comment: is it possible to scroll smoothly and select a specific chapter without playing random chapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend you to convert all vector images to raster. It's very hard for processor to animate vector images.

Delete all code after `drop_me` function.

Write this:

```
scrolling_manu.buttons_all.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
scrolling_manu.buttons_all.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);

var touchedPart:MovieClip;
var posY:int;

function onTouchBegin(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    touchedPart = event.target as MovieClip;
    posY = scrolling_manu.buttons_all.y;
}

function onTouchEnd(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    // if list was been moved, that isn't a tap.
    if (posY == scrolling_manu.buttons_all.y)
    {
        trace("part tapped", touchedPart.name);
        touchedPart.gotoAndPlay("over1");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/subdan/724721f54195b7ff4f9a) it's all code that you should copy to frame 1 of layer "local action".

Comment: Do you want to cut digit 12 from string "part12"? Try this: `var n:String = touchedPart.name; var index:int = n.match(/\d+/)[0]; trace("part tapped", index);`

Comment: your idea works but i don't want to cut 12 digit from string "part12" .in my project  i have 40 buttons(child movie clips(part1,part2,part3......)that you saw) and 40 frame labels("part1","part2","part3"......) i want part 1 Movieclip is connected to part1 frame label  same as part2 to part2  frame label .......i want when i click to part1 Movie clip it will go to part1 frame label to play an animation or if i click part2 Movie clip it will go to part2 frame label  ...is it possible to keep movie clips and frame label in array and matching them and play them with the button click?

Comment: 12 it's an example. You can cut either digit.

Comment: `touchedPart.name` it's a name of touched item (ex. part3). Expression `match(/\d+/)[0]` returns digit after `part` word. So you can write `gotoAndStop("part" + index)`.